# How to create a grid of views with dynamic height in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I would like to create a grid of boxes, which are `Label`'s with fixed width and height within my `UITableViewCell`'s. How can this be done?

**I want this:**

[image]

**I get this:**

[image]

I tried using a `UICollectionView` within the `UITableViewCell` but I am running in to two problems:

- the `UITableViewCell`'s height is not dynamically changing according to how many items there are
- the space between items can't be set exactly (since you can only define a minCellSpacing value)

**My Question:**

What is the best way to create this grid of `Label`'s such that the `UITableViewCell`'s height will change dynamically based on number of items, and so I can set the spacing between items exactly?

(If it can be done without `UICollectionView` that would be nice, but it's not a requirement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an updated version of the `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method that ensures that the labels are 30x30:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    let count = 16 + Int(arc4random_uniform(16))
    print(count)

    let rows = Int(ceil(Double(count) / Double(ColumnCount)))

    let columnView = LMColumnView()

    for var i = 0; i < rows; i++ {
        let rowView = LMRowView()
        rowView.height = 30

        columnView.addArrangedSubview(rowView)

        for var j = 0; j < ColumnCount; j++ {
            let number = Int(arc4random_uniform(150))

            let label = UILabel()

            if (i * ColumnCount + j < count) {
                label.text = String(number)
                label.width = 30
                label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
                label.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            }

            rowView.addArrangedSubview(label)
        }

        rowView.addArrangedSubview(LMSpacer())
    }

    appendMarkupElementView(columnView)
}
```

[image]

It uses the default spacing of 8 pixels, but you can change that via the `spacing` property of `LMColumnView` and `LMRowView`.

Comment: This looks awesome Greg. Last thing: can the column count be dynamic to fill the width?

Comment: Yes - you'd just need to write some basic logic to calculate how many 30-pixel-wide label cells will fit within the current table view cell width.

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting iOS 9, you could do this by adding a collection of `UIStackView`s to your cell. The outer stack view would be vertical, and each row would be a horizontal stack view. You could use `FillEqually` for the distribution to ensure that all of the cells are the same width.

Alternatively, you could consider using `LMColumnView` and `LMRowView` from the [MarkupKit](https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit) framework, which supports iOS 8. Here's an example:

[image: Cell Grid Example]

The source code for the view controller looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    let GridCellIdentifier = "gridCell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.registerClass(GridCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: GridCellIdentifier)

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 2;
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 6;
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(GridCellIdentifier)!
    }
}
```

The cell code looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import MarkupKit

class GridCell: LMTableViewCell {
    let ColumnCount = 7

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        let count = 16 + Int(arc4random_uniform(16))

        let rows = Int(ceil(Double(count) / Double(ColumnCount)))

        let columnView = LMColumnView()

        for var i = 0; i < rows; i++ {
            let rowView = LMRowView()
            rowView.height = 40

            columnView.addArrangedSubview(rowView)

            for var j = 0; j < ColumnCount; j++ {
                let number = Int(arc4random_uniform(150))

                let label = UILabel()

                if (i * ColumnCount + j < count) {
                    label.text = String(number)
                    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
                    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
                }

                label.weight = 1.0

                rowView.addArrangedSubview(label)
            }
        }

        appendMarkupElementView(columnView)
    }

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
    }
}
```

Basically, it generates a random number to represent the number of labels in each cell, then creates as many rows and labels as it needs to populate the cell. Empty labels are created to ensure that everything aligns.

Comment: Thanks Greg. How can I force the width and height of each cell to be 30x30 pts?

Comment: I'll add another answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Uicollection View in Uitableview Cell itself .....else you will need to calculate the height of your Uitableview cell for no.of boxes you want to add in each cell...But i think collectionview is better way to achieve this can i know why you dont want to use uicollection view...

Comment: I don't mind using a collection view, but how can the TableViewCell's height be set based on number of items?

Comment: As width and hieght of each box is fixed ,then you know the spacing between boxed and width of sceen so you can calculate the no. Of boxes will fit in particular width then for. Ex ypu have 10 box 50*50 so assume the the spacing of 10 between boxes and let screen width is 300 then 50*5=250 and spacing between each boxes 10*5 =50 so 250+50 =300 and same for next line ....thus  10 boxes created two lines therefore height will be 50 +50 +vertical spacing and otherwise in collection view you can set content height of collection view to height of UITable view cell.

Comment: Okay great. Once I compute the CollectionViews height how do I set it?

Comment: Just PIN collection View (Top | Bottom | Leading | Trailing) From UItableview cell and set the height of UITableview Cell in 'heightForRowAtIndexPath' this will automatically adjust the Collection View Height .