# Create grid view using UITableView in swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I am trying to create a grid view using UITableView.I can achive it with collectionView but I want to make it with tableview. I am not finding the suitable answer on google.Please help.

[image]

Comment: Make one cell for each row (2 elements per cell). If you have an uneven number of items use another type of cell.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752543/how-to-create-a-grid-of-views-with-dynamic-height-in-uitableviewcell

Comment: You can use UICollectionView inside UITableView

Comment: i think this may help you : https://www.thorntech.com/2015/08/want-your-swift-app-to-scroll-in-two-directions-like-netflix-heres-how/

Comment: Should each column act independently of the other?